# Find_package not working with library from source

Tags: c++, makefile, linker, cmake, aruco

I have a library that I installed from source.
It looks fine, the install manifest shows that all files I need have been installed:

```
/usr/local/lib/cmake/Findaruco.cmake
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/aruco-uninstalled.pc
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/aruco.pc
/usr/local/lib/libaruco.so.2.0.7
/usr/local/lib/libaruco.so.2.0
/usr/local/lib/libaruco.so
/usr/local/include/aruco/marker.h
/usr/local/include/aruco/markerdetector.h
/usr/local/include/aruco/dictionary.h
/usr/local/include/aruco/levmarq.h
/usr/local/include/aruco/markermap.h
/usr/local/include/aruco/cameraparameters.h
/usr/local/include/aruco/posetracker.h
/usr/local/include/aruco/exports.h
/usr/local/include/aruco/markerlabeler.h
/usr/local/include/aruco/cvdrawingutils.h
/usr/local/include/aruco/ar_omp.h
/usr/local/include/aruco/aruco.h
/usr/local/include/aruco/dictionary_based.h
/usr/local/include/aruco/svmmarkers.h
/usr/local/bin/aruco_tracker
/usr/local/bin/aruco_simple
/usr/local/bin/aruco_test
/usr/local/bin/aruco_print_marker
/usr/local/bin/aruco_print_dictionary
/usr/local/bin/aruco_markermap_pix2meters
/usr/local/bin/aruco_simple_markermap
/usr/local/bin/aruco_test_markermap
/usr/local/bin/aruco_calibration
/usr/local/bin/aruco_calibration_fromimages
```

I can also include the headers that I need from that library in my project; they are found.

What does not work is actually linking the library.
my cmakeLists has the following line:

```
find_package(aruco REQUIRED)
```

I would think that that would be enough, since the Findaruco.cmake file is in
/usr/local/lib/cmake. However, cmake is unable to find the library. 
I also noticed that 
`locate .so | grep aruco` does not actually find the library. It's output is:

```
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_aruco.so
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_aruco.so.3.1
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_aruco.so.3.1.0
```

So something is obviously wrong.
I additionally noticed that on installation cmake tells me the following (along with others from that library):

```
Removed runtime path from "/usr/local/lib/libaruco.so.2.0.7"
```

Does that have anything to do with it?
If you need a look at the library, you can find it [here on sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/aruco/files/2.0.7/).
I can't build without it, how do I get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so [cmake modules](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_MODULE_PATH.html) are searched for in specific paths. I believe the default is something along the lines of `/usr/share/cmake/<version>/modules`

you could set the cmake_module_path variable to the directory you installed the Findaruco cmake file into, or move that module to the location wherever your other cmake files are.

side note: if you have not run `$ sudo updatedb` then `$ locate` will not reveal the new libraries you installed because it has not been added to the database for locate

Comment: Alright thanks, I copied the Findaruco.cmake file to a /modules folder in my project and set the CMAKE_MODULE_PATH to that. It works now. I do think however that the creator of the aruco library should have made an arucoConfig.cmake file.

Comment: yes he should have, iirc it's relatively newer (maybe version 3 of cmake?) so maybe the aruco lib is older idk, glad that solved your problem